# Extract specific object properties from a list of objects into a list

Tags: c#, object, lambda, properties

I have the following List of Interfaces:

```
List<IInterfaces> instantiatedInterfaces;
```

`IInterfaces` has the following properties:

```
List<StandardPort> ListOfPorts { get; }
UInt16 NumberOfPorts { get; }
```

`StandardPort` has the property:

```
public Uint16 Side { get; set; }
```

Now, assuming `instantiatedInterfaces` has been populated correctly, how can I extract into a `List<StandardPort>`, all the ports of the `ListOfPorts` (for a specific `Side`) of all the Interfaces contained by `instantiatedInterfaces`

What I have tried (not working - return an empty list):

```
List<StandardPort> foundPorts = instantiatedInterfaces.Select(i => i.ListOfPorts.Where(p => p.side == Left)) as List<StandardPort>;
```

Comment: Can you let us know and example of what is populated in the instantiatedInterfaces and what do you expect as output in the result list?

Comment: You want one list with all the ports that have a specific side?

Comment: @pappbence96 - That's correct

Comment: @Azhar Khorasany - Hopefully not relevant (I provided the Interface), why do you need more than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the 'list of lists' into a single list with `Enumerable.SelectMany`:

```
var allPorts = instantiatedInterfaces.SelectMany(iface => iface.ListOfPorts);
```

Then you can filter this list with `Enumerable.Where`:

```
var foundPorts = allPorts.Where(port => port.Side == Left).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8)

```
List<StandardPort> result = instantiatedInterfaces
             .SelectMany(w => w.ListOfPorts)
             .Where(p => p.side == Left)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had to close my bracket before using ".Where", I see + SelectMany :-)

Answer (score 2):

```cs
List<StandardPort> ports = instantiatedInterfaces
    .SelectMany(intf => intf.ListOfPorts)
    .Where(port => port.side == Left)
    .ToList();
```